# International bank transfer, what is safe to share?

Tags: banks

Okay, so I am selling a smartphone, to the guy who lives in UK, or that is what he says. So for the money transfer he asks me these things.

Name

Bank Name

Account Number

Iban

Swift Code.

Is it okay to give them to him, BTW I live in the Latvia, and he already knows my email, whats connected to my bank account and he may know my mobile phone number, whats also connected.

Comment: give iban and your name.

Comment: Why not call your bank?

Answer (score 1):

All these fields are needed to transfer Euros internationally.

Both the UK and Latvia are part of [SEPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Euro_Payments_Area); WP says:

> SEPA clearance is based on the IBAN bank-account identification and the SWIFT-BIC bank identifier.

The bank name and account number can be derived from the IBAN; they are not strictly needed, but it does not hurt to give them.